# Child theme not using parent theme css/styles/formatting?

Tags: themes, child-theme

I am making a simple child theme of the ["Grow Minimal"](https://wordpress.org/themes/grow-minimal/) theme.

I created a folder, `grow-minimal-child` and added `functions.php` and `style.css`:

`functions.php`:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'grow-thinkup-style-minimal'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('thinkup-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

and `style.css`:

```
/*
Theme Name: Grow Minimal Child
Theme URI: https://www.thinkupthemes.com/free/grow/
Author: Think Up Themes
Author URI: https://www.thinkupthemes.com
Description: Created for customizing...
Template: grow
Version: 1.0.1
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: one-column, two-columns, three-columns, right-sidebar, left-sidebar, custom-header, custom-menu, full-width-template, theme-options, threaded-comments, editor-style, featured-images, featured-image-header, post-formats, sticky-post, translation-ready, flexible-header, custom-background, grid-layout, footer-widgets, blog, e-commerce, portfolio, rtl-language-support
Text Domain: grow-minimal-child
*/
```

So, if you see I didn't really add any CSS.  However, now when I activate this child theme, and visit the site, it looks a bit different.  As if the parent CSS was completely overlooked.  I also tried using `$parent_style = 'parent-style'`, `$parent_style = 'thinkup-style'`.

Here's the `functions.php` inside `Grow-minimal` folder:

```
function grow_thinkup_child_frontscripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'thinkup-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'thinkup-bootstrap' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'grow-thinkup-style-minimal', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'thinkup-style' ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'grow_thinkup_child_frontscripts' );
```

When I change my theme back to just `Grow Minimal`, the site looks as expected.

Where's the css going wrong (or more likely, where am I not updating or linking the child to parent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme you're trying to use as a parent, [Grow Minimal](https://wordpress.org/themes/grow-minimal/), is a child theme of the [Grow theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/grow/). It's not possible to create a child theme of another child theme without writing custom code workarounds.

In your code, these two lines just do the same thing twice:

```
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('thinkup-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
```

They enqueue the stylesheet for the parent theme, Grow. The Grow Minimal theme is ignored. [This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65852/is-it-possible-to-make-grandchild-themes) provides more context about the problems with grandchild themes.

In this case, the best practice is to simply add your custom styles or template code directly to the off-the-shelf child theme (Grow Minimal), effectively converting it to a custom theme. You'll still be able to apply any updates to the unmodified parent theme without losing your customizations.

Comment: So, if my main reason for creating a child theme would be to add a custom `page-allposts.php` type file, and adding custom CSS...I could just include those new files in the Grow Minimal theme?  I know it's highly recommended to not make changes to a **parent** theme's files (functions.php, etc), but is it okay to do so for a child theme that I did not create?

Comment: Yep, that's the recommended way to handle that scenario. You'll still be able to benefit from any updates to the unmodified parent theme.

Comment: Thanks! (Mind editing that point in to the answer? That would, in my eyes, fully complete what I was asking about)

Comment: No problem, done!